# How to create and execute procedures in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I created a Spatial table Points using SQL Editor in MySQL workbench. To fill this table,
the following is the code I am using.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_points( 
IN size INT(10) 
) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE i DOUBLE(10,1) DEFAULT size; 

DECLARE lon FLOAT(7,4); 
DECLARE lat FLOAT(6,4); 
DECLARE position VARCHAR(100); 

-- Deleting all. 
DELETE FROM Points; 

WHILE i > 0 DO 
SET lon = RAND() * 360 - 180; 
SET lat = RAND() * 180 - 90; 

SET position = CONCAT( 'POINT(', lon, ' ', lat, ')' ); 

INSERT INTO Points(name, location) VALUES ( CONCAT('name_', i), GeomFromText(position) ); 

SET i = i - 1; 
END WHILE; 
END
```

when I executed it, it shows the error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your               MySQL server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Executing the statement

`CALL fill_points(1000);`

shows the same error

I even don't know whether the way I proceed is correct or not.

Can anybody help me...

Comment: ; is missing after the last END

Comment: @Pete `;` is not needed to place after end in procedure if she is using any tool like navicat etc.

Answer (score 13):

Have you ended the entire query? Try setting a **delimiter**, and use it after the END so the server knows you finished the command.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_points( 
IN size INT(10) 
) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE i DOUBLE(10,1) DEFAULT size; 

DECLARE lon FLOAT(7,4); 
DECLARE lat FLOAT(6,4); 
DECLARE position VARCHAR(100); 

-- Deleting all. 
DELETE FROM Points; 

WHILE i > 0 DO 
SET lon = RAND() * 360 - 180; 
SET lat = RAND() * 180 - 90; 

SET position = CONCAT( 'POINT(', lon, ' ', lat, ')' ); 

INSERT INTO Points(name, location) VALUES ( CONCAT('name_', i), GeomFromText(position) ); 

SET i = i - 1; 
END WHILE; 
END //
delimiter ;
```

#### Also, by the by

While `DELETE FROM TABLE` does remove all data from the table, `TRUNCATE table` does so faster. Unless you have good reasons to use `DELETE` (they exist), `TRUNCATE` might be what you want.

Comment: It seems to me that regarding this delimiter thing you're absolutely right Konerak! I've seen 'delimiter' pops out here and there in explanations and manuals, but I was pretty sure it should be used in mysql command line utility only. It's really surprising one have to use it in a GUI utility like MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Hi , I am getting super admin privileges error when applying a stored procedure . Can you tell me what type privileges i have to get to create a stored procedure.