# How to define a table in SQL with 2 fields being not-null (mandatory) dependent?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Not-null dependent means that at least 1 field is not null.

Ideas?

Example: email and phone-number can be not-null dependent. If email is null, phone-number must  be not-null. If phone-number is null, email must be not-null.

Comment: Someone added a tsql tag and you mention mysql in comments. What is the correct tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraints, despite [this feature having been requested since 2004.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464)

Annoyingly, it parses CHECK constraint syntax, but it doesn't store the constraint or enforce it later. I have thought for a long time that this is misleading to accept an SQL statement that the RDBMS has no support for, without reporting even a warning.

To solve your problem, you could use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF COALESCE(NEW.email, NEW.phone_number) IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Either email or phone_number must be non-null';
    END IF;
END
```

You also need to define a similar trigger before UPDATE.

Comment: Got the error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, I did test this trigger before posting it. I suspect you haven't set the DELIMITER correctly, and the SQL parser thinks that the first semicolon terminates the whole CREATE TRIGGER statement. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745538/create-function-through-mysqldb/745575#745575

Comment: Found a nice answer that visualizes the delimiter thingy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10084557/435605

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  EMAIL VARCHAR(256),
  PHONE VARCHAR(10)
);

ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT
  CHECK (EMAIL IS NOT NULL) OR (PHONE IS NOT NULL);
```

Some SQL dialects allow or require you to put the `CHECK` constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Tested on mysql. Had to change to: `CHECK ((EMAIL IS NOT NULL) OR (PHONE IS NOT NULL));` - added parenthesis.

Comment: On mysql, it doesn't work. The statement passed OK but had no affect. It wasn't registered as a constraint and 2 nulls in the same row could be added.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table the_table add constraint check_two_columns 
     check (   (email is null and phone_number is not null) 
            or (email is not null and phone_number is null));
```

You didn't state your DBMS, but this will not work with MySQL however.

Comment: Indeed doesn't work with mysql. I thought such a question was generic enough for SQL :( Any idea how to do it in mysql?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: the only (ugly) way to do this in MySQL is to write a trigger (or upgrade to Postgres)

Comment: The strange thing is that the command didn't fail. It just didn't do anything - no constraint was created.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: yes, that's the MySQL way. Rather than throwing an exception it silently ignores things (or silently truncates data)