# Create a table with every month since given date

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create a table with only one column that holds every month since a given date? 
For instance with the given date 2016-01-01 I would like the following table:

[image: Table of interest]

Comment: Yes, its possible but why you need it.... if you explain the scenario may be people can suggest more...

Comment: Do you mean you want a query that auto-generates those dates?

Comment: Yes I want a query that autogenerate those dates.
I want to sum the amount of some dynamic tables up to all of those dates. 
So for instance it could be a given customers consumption up to those dates

Comment: I am running MySQL workbench 6.3 and it does not seem that it supports creating procedures. 
There doesn't exist a more down to earth and less efficient method for doing this such that Workbench are capable of running it?

Comment: Workbench is a visual tool for using the database, not the database. It might not give you a pretty interface option to create a procedure, but it can't not support it. Also, existance of questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084458/how-to-create-and-execute-procedures-in-mysql-workbench shows that it should work.

Comment: Okay I see that the problem is that my access is denied to the database when running the command. Guess this is a necessary condition to solve the asked question.